# Get contents of all the files in all the folders

Tags: bash, algorithm, ls

There is a directory with some folders like **a**, **b**, **c**...

In every folder there are some text files which contents I need to get.
I've already tried to write a script like

```
for i in `ls`;
do
        cd $i ;
        cat * ;
done
```

But it doesn't work (I know why, but I don't know how to do it properly)

Comment: There is a directory with some folders like **a, b, c...** Wrong. There is a directory that contains subdirectories. There are no "folders" on Linux. ***Never*** use `for i in $(ls anything)`, see [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) Depending on whether the order of the files is important, you can either use `find` or enable `globstar`.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't [parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Instead use the `find` command to get all your files.

If you want to display the content of all regular files in the current directory and all its subdirectories, use this command:

```
find -type f -exec cat {} \;
```

If you have a lot of subdirectories, you may want to restrict the depth level with the option `-maxdepth`.